# Borderlands 2 mission glitch

Tags: borderlands-2

I accidentally teleported to the wrong area in *Borderlands 2*. When I did that, I was given a Level 50 mission, even though I'm a Level 12. I can only assume that this was a glitch. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What area? And what did you do to get to that "wrong area"?

Comment: You need to provide more information, please clarify your question: Where were you before, how is the place called, where you are now?
(There are DLC areas to do later in the game, but accesible almost from the beginning)

Comment: Teleport back, and ignore the new suicidal mission.

Answer (score 4):

You probably teleported into the area added by a DLC. The game will automatically provide you with a "story" quest which will tell you the story of the DLC area. This is not a glitch, this is usual behavior. Just as regular areas, DLCs have a minimum level requirement and you should not think about starting them until you hit it.

Since this is a level 50 mission, i think you teleported into [The Raid of Digistruct Peak](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Raid_on_Digistruct_Peak).